# Android - Webview height is increased after scroll

Tags: java, android, android-listview, scrollview, listitem

I am developing an android application in which I have used webview instead of Textview to use the **justify** property on each list item .

**list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/question"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Question"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
<View 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@color/color_black"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/select_yes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Yes"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/select_no"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="No"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**CustomListAdapter.java**

In `getView()`

```
String question = "<html><body>"

            + "<p align=\"justify\">"

            + data.get(position).getStudyCrit()

            + "</p> "

            + "</body></html>";
holder.question.loadData(question, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

If I run the application, the [image]

But,After I change the scroll position and again go to previous position. the height of webview is increased like below,

[image]

**Note :** There is no issues with `TextView`, the problem arised when I replaced `TextView` with `WebView`

Please help me finding the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use TextView instead of WebView and in TextView you can set text like:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(question));
```

And you can define maxLines for TextView.

Comment: I tried like this . But Justifying the string does not work

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use webview just to justify the content. You can use the following code:

```
String question = "<html><body>"

        + "<p align=\"justify\">"

        + data.get(position).getStudyCrit()

        + "</p> "

        + "</body></html>";
yourtextview.setText(Html.fromHtml(question));
```

Comment: No . I tried this . But Justifying the string content does not work :-(